# How to get the filename from HTTP GET request

Tags: c, http, get

I am trying to add a modification to [Axel](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/) to get the proper filename this should be done in C language.

Currently a link such as https://put.io/v2/files/49667352/download?token=851a95c6230211e2a896003048fa303a would be saved under the filename 49667352 therfore

However when downloading from the webbrowser or a download manager such as IDM it captures the filename such as movie.mp4 sent from the server  after the first Get request. How can I add that implemenation  with C language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the response that comes from the server, there is a header called [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). Value of this header holds some info about the  file being downloaded. So, you can find the file name in this header.

An example of this header:

```
Content-Disposition : attachment; filename="movie.mp4"
```